# Spring Security SQLException

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Подключил к учебному проекту Spring security. Но не слишком успешно. Пользовался этим tutorial:

https://tutorials.webencyclop.com/spring-boot/03-create-user-login-registration/#define-controllers-for-login-registration   Подскажите пожалуйста почему Spring выбрасывает SQL Exception  **java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).** когда я пытаюсь залогониться. Провел куча часов пытаясь выяснить что не так, но так и не выяснил. Мой проект на гитхаб: https://github.com/SerhiiRyzhkov/english

Мой конфиг:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            // URLs matching for access rights
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_USER", "ADMIN_USER", "SITE_USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()

            // form login
            .csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            // logout
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
   }


}
```

Мой контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    modelAndView.setViewName("login"); 
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView register() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    // User user = new User();
    // modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("register"); 
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public ModelAndView home() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("home"); 
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

JSP форма:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
   <title>English - login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
      Login
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" th:placeholder="Email"/>
      <br>
      Password
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" th:placeholder="Password"/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit" th:text="Login"></button>
      <a href="/recover-password">Forgot password?</a>
      </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Мой properies file:

```
 #Spring Security login queries
 security.basic.enabled=false
 spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, '1' as enabled from auth_user where email=? and  status='VERIFIED'
 spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role_name from auth_user u inner join auth_user_role ur on(u.auth_user_id=ur.auth_user_id) inner join auth_role r on(ur.auth_role_id=r.auth_role_id) where u.email=?
```

Когда я пытаюсь залогониться, я вижу что данные с формы уходят в контроллер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что проблема в моем sql statement, но он практически такой же по синтаксису как дефолтный запрос в `JdbcDaoImpl.class`.

update

SQL Exception java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Возникает в момент когда в форме логин пароль я нажимаю кнопку сабмит. В этот момент происходит запрос в базу данных, проверить имеются ли такие email и пароль в БД, и каков статус данного юзера? (забанен или нет). Сами запросы вынесены в файл application.properies - запросы приведены выше. Эти запросы инницируются с помощью

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
```

в классе SecurityConfiga. А сами statements передаются переменными usersQuery и rolesQuery. Ожидалось, что при вводе логина и пароля, SecurityConfig проверяет есть ли в базе такой пользователь или нет и впускает в приложение если пароль совпал в БД и статус usera VERIFIED. но меня не отправляет на страницу home и нет сообщения о успешном логине, а выбрасывается исключение

Comment: Если нужно добавить какую-либо информацию, или есть у кого- какие идеи - пишите. Буду рад

Comment: В вопросе надо указывать только релевантный код. Зачем тут конфигурация spring security если ошибка `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)`?

Comment: @RomanC потому что не работает запрос от Spring Security к базе данных. (Как я понял из ошибки, но это не точно). То есть проблема либо в конфигурации части security либо в двух запросах sql из пропертей. Я привел и то и другое. Решил предоставить полную информацию, которая может быть связана

Comment: Уточните вашу проблему. Из того что написано ничего невозможно понять. Где выполняется запрос к бд? Где код который выполняет этот запрос?

Comment: @RomanC Расписал еще подробней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расписал все что просили в комментах, но ответа не последовало. Поэтому в итоге пришел к такому решению: (вдруг кому понадобится). Я имплементировал UserDetailsService в сервис-слое для entity User и переопределил метод **loadUserByUsername**:

```
  @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findById(s);

        if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid email or password");
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Role role: user.getRoleSet())
            authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(s, user.getPassword(), user.getEnabled(), true, true, true, authorityList);
    }
```

после этого, я уже мог это использовать в конфигурации Spring Security:

```
@Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).
                passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```